# Unity Bar auto-hide behaviour and application icons placement

Tags: 11.04, unity

The first issue:

It seems that sometimes when I hover to the left edge of the screen the Unity Bar will not stay on top of other windows even if I continue to hover the cursor above it, at other times it will stay on top.

Is this a normal behaviour? Or am I affected by some bug / inconsistency? If it's normal, what's the logic behind it?

The second issue:

Application icons for running applications do not maintain their position in the Unity Bar but instead move around according to some weird rules (if any?) that I can't understand.

Is this to be expected, or is it a bug? Is there a way to force them to stop moving around? I like to see certain apps in certain positions and this bothers me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First issue: bug.

- Please report it.

Second issue (you really should ask two separate questions, but I will answer anyway :)!:

- Unity uses fixed locations for applications that have actually been added to the launcher manually (favourites). So for example, if you run Nautilus, it will always appear in the same location as your Home folder icon (at the top by default). However, if for example, you install a new application without adding it to the launcher, and run it, unity will simply place this application below your favourites (in what ever space is available). This may make it seem as if applications are moving around (scary ain't it?), but in fact, they are not! They are just falling into place where ever there is room to do so. To get your applications to "stay in one place" (and don't move!!!):

  1. Open the Dash.
  2. Start typing the name of the application until it appears.
  3. Click and drag the application icon to the spot on the launcher where you would like it to be.
  4. From now on the application will stay in the same place unless you move it to another location :)!

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work that way, so I assume the second issue must be a bug as well. If I have an application icon right in the middle of the Unity Bar (a non-pinned one, mind you, as I don't like to fill my Unity Bar with pinned apps) and I minimize and then restore this said app, it will be moved to the bottom of the Unity Bar! Bummer!

Comment: @Andrei: that's likely a bug. I don't have that problem btw.

Comment: Can you please try while making sure that you have non-pinned icons both above and below this icon we're testing with?

Comment: Also, I think it might not happen with all applications. Can you please use Banshee as the app we're testing with?

Comment: @Andrei: if it's Banshee - I had a problem with Banshee before, so it's probably a transient bug.

Comment: Other programs exhibiting this behaviour: Transmission, Krusader. It seems to go like this: 1.) a new icon is created at the bottom when the app is restored (as if it can't see it's already there) 2.) It then realizes there are 2 (duplicate) icons of this app, and it will remove the first one.

FWIW, I have submitted 2 bug reports for these (hopefully I'm not just creating additional noise there, this really is an issue for me and I do believe I might not be the only one).

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/773762

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/773760

Comment: I've noticed a problem with Banshee and some other applications as well. It seems to be a problem with unity not tracking the application correctly if it is not launched from the unity launcher. For example if I open Banshee from the sound menu, it shows up separately from the launcher's icon.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've added it to the bug report. Might be the case, as I tend to run many apps from startup scripts, or from scripts created to run frequently used apps.

Comment: Update: doesn't seem to have anything to do with apps not being started from the Launcher; please see my updated steps to reproduce here, and try to confirm if possible: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/773762

Comment: Update 2: Make sure when following those steps that you first click on your desktop before activating Banshee.

Answer (score 0):

First issue: The Unity bar opens fully only when you reach the far top left corner of the screen. When you do that it stays open and on top for a period of time (at least for me) or permanently, i.e. as long as i hold my cursor over the ubuntu logo.

Second issue: Applications that you keep in the launcher should definitely maintain their positions (mine do). Application that you open and are not in the launcher appear just above the workspace switcher.

Comment: Indeed, when doing the top-left-corner activation, it will always stay on top. When I'm doing the left-edge activation, in ~90% of the cases it will stay on top, in the rest of the cases it will hide itself rather quickly even though I'm still hovering above it. This certainly looks like a bug.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the behavior on my system. Hovering over the launcher keeps it on top (however i tend to turn of left edge opening and leave only top left edge; i don't like launchers popping out by mistake :)